# How to show an image in Surface in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Do anyone have a solution for showing an xml shape as a background by using the Jetpack Compose widget Surface ?

Do I need to use DrawImage, or is there a simpler approach ?

In the example below I want to exchange the `Color.Blue` with a xml file called `side_nav_bar.xml` which is actually a gradient created with `<shape> </shape>`

```
@Composable
private fun AppDrawer(
    currentScreen: Screen,
    closeDrawer: () -> Unit
)
{
val topImage = +imageResource(R.mipmap.empty_1024)


Column(
    crossAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand,
    mainAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand
) {

    Surface(color = Color.Blue)
    {
        Column(
            mainAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand,
            crossAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand)
        {
            Padding(8.dp) {
                Container(expanded = true, height = 100.dp, width = 100.dp){
                    Clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)) {
                        DrawImage(image = topImage)
                    }
                }
            }

            Padding(8.dp){
                Text(text = "Fuel Empty")
            }

            Padding(8.dp){
                Text(text = "https://www.fuelpump.no")
            }


        }

    }

    Divider()

    DrawerButton(
        icon = R.drawable.ic_baseline_store_24,
        label = "Stations",
        isSelected = currentScreen == Screen.Stations
    ){
        navigateTo(Screen.Stations)
        closeDrawer()
    }

    DrawerButton(
        icon = R.drawable.ic_baseline_map_24,
        label = "Overview",
        isSelected = currentScreen == Screen.Overview
    ){
        navigateTo(Screen.Overview)
        closeDrawer()
    }

    DrawerButton(
        icon = R.drawable.ic_baseline_format_list_numbered_24,
        label = "Statistics",
        isSelected = currentScreen == Screen.Statistics
    ){
        navigateTo(Screen.Statistics)
        closeDrawer()
    }

    Divider()

    DrawerButton(
        icon = R.drawable.ic_baseline_settings_applications_24,
        label = "Settings",
        isSelected = currentScreen == Screen.Settings
    ){
        closeDrawer()
    }

    DrawerButton(
        icon = R.drawable.ic_baseline_build_24,
        label = "Tools",
        isSelected = currentScreen == Screen.Tools
    ){
        closeDrawer()
    }

    DrawerButton(
        icon = R.drawable.ic_baseline_help_24,
        label = "Help",
        isSelected = currentScreen == Screen.Help
    ){
        closeDrawer()
    }



}
}
```

xml I want to use as background:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
        android:angle="135"
        android:centerColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:endColor="@color/ic_black_background"
        android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:type="linear"/>
</shape>
```

RG

Comment: did you found a solution for this? Please update

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm sorry to say that I had to leave Compose for a while due to other things.

Comment: Thanks @Roar I also couldn't find a way to do so I just assumed that it's still not supported yet. A hack it to export you shape as an `svg` and render it using `vectorResource(id=...)`

Comment: Of course, but originally I want it more simple than that. We all want it simpler. And I hoped for a while that Compose could do it, but I found that I often painted myself into a corner using Compose rather than traditional XML and ordinary kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

try this function. I fixed my problem.

```
inline fun Image(
  asset:        VectorAsset,
  modifier:     Modifier     = Modifier,
  alignment:    Alignment    = Alignment.Center,
  contentScale: ContentScale = ContentScale.Inside,
  alpha:        Float        = DefaultAlpha,
  colorFilter:  ColorFilter? = null
)
```

Comment: I'll check that out, if other hasn't.